# Why my Maven project automatic generate apidoc in target folder?

Tags: maven, javadoc

I didn't configurated maven-javadoc-plugin in my maven project pom.xml file,but when I run mvn install command,then generate apidoc?

configuration of pom.xml as follow :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<build>
    <finalName>webcnmobile</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- web.xml is not mandatory since JavaEE 5 -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

the spring-security-oauth-parent pom.xml see [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.springframework.security.oauth|spring-security-oauth-parent|2.0.3.RELEASE|pom)

Comment: do you use a prant pom from womewhere? try mvn help:effective-pom and have a look what plugins are configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc plugin is configured in the parent pom that you are referencing (spring-security-oauth-parent). This means that you [inherit](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) this configuration and it automatically gets applied to your project.

The configuration in the parent pom is as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>javadoc</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This is then being applied to your project and hence you are getting javadoc generated.